# How i can create pdf file at hosting server url using Angular4 with kendo-filesaver

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

```
const options = <PDFOptions>{ paperSize: "A4", landscape: false };

ReportName = GenerateGUID();
exportPDF(group, options).then((data) => {  
 saveAs(data, ReportName + ".pdf", { proxyURL: '/Reports/'});        
});
```

Hi, i want to create pdf file on specific folder at web hosting path. can some one will help me to resolve it.

Comment: Whats the problem, console error?

Comment: if you want to create the pdf on the server, you need to do it on ther server, notthe client side code

Answer (score 0):

You can not create a PDF file on the server. If you want this, then check [Reporting](https://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx). Check the [demo](https://demos.telerik.com/reporting/invoice?&skinName=default) and help how to [integrate with Angular](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/angular-report-viewer).

Client side [pdf export](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/pdfexport/) is used when you want to offer user an option to export part of your page.
For example: when you want to offer user that only partial of your page could be  printed (without header, menus, footer ...). Only relevant data.